# Finding number of combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, combinations

I realize this may be more of a math problem than an actual programming problem. I'm trying to figure this out with python.

So the user is going to specify a range of numbers to me, the min range being 1-2 and max being 1-99. I then have to tell the user how many 3 number combinations can be made in that range. However, the combinations can ONLY be in increasing numeric order. So for example, if the given range is 1-50, I can't say 45 - 10 - 20 is a combination, because it is not in increasing numeric order.

Comment: ...and Your Question?

Comment: I have to output a integer that represents the # of 3-number combinations (increasing numbers only) in a given range. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: That's still not a question.  Asking people to solve your assignments is off-topic for stackoverflow.  Instead you should describe what you've tried, show us your code, then explain what you're having trouble with and the specific issues/errors you're having.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: The problem is I don't even know where to start with this one, besides the basic ask for the range input.

Comment: Is `(1,1,2)` the same as `(1,2,1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `itertools` module.

```
import itertools
numbers = range(1,100)
items = set(list(itertools.combinations(numbers,3)))
for item in items:
    print item
```

It seems to give the desired output.

Be aware: It seems to take a long time (**Edit:** to print it all at once.).

This is part of the output:

```
, 73, 75), (76, 86, 91), (42, 91, 92), (8, 54, 71), (11, 54, 87), (37, 79, 86), (2, 17, 32), (44, 67, 78), (14, 24, 56), (10, 64, 79), (9, 90, 94), (39, 52, 88), (62, 78, 90), (9, 60, 71), (23, 25, 30), (5, 27, 92), (33, 74, 78), (68, 70, 84), (48, 79, 95), (8, 70, 95), (23, 68, 78), (14, 45, 78), (8, 36, 73), (72, 86, 88), (13, 26, 74), (35, 60, 86), (3, 29, 76), (6, 15, 74), (46, 54, 73), (7, 41, 88), (48, 59, 90), (23, 30, 73), (71, 83, 91), (42, 78, 96), (44, 60, 92), (27, 46, 68), (27, 72, 88), (34, 74, 78), (24, 55, 93), (84, 93, 97), (32, 36, 73), (7, 31, 38), (28, 43, 66), (29, 37, 40), (19, 33, 96), (45, 66, 77), (25, 66, 72), (22, 60, 74), (59, 60, 76), (30, 57, 82), (11, 16, 51), (41, 48, 99), (5, 21, 86), (18, 27, 98), (26, 34, 95), (19, 72, 74), (32, 34, 35), (43, 68, 93), (36, 57, 77), (20, 50, 90), (25, 71, 99), (47, 74, 87), (9, 26, 35), (20, 24, 89), (27, 67, 83), (3, 19, 70), (20, 72, 79), (24, 36, 79), (8, 25, 43), (49, 53, 87), (24, 63, 68), (21, 63, 92), (21, 56, 72), (26, 43, 87), (79, 92, 94), (22, 41, 98), (45, 55, 88), (30, 46, 94), (38, 71, 79), (17, 51, 81), (43, 65, 97), (40, 56, 72), (19, 62, 88), (31, 38, 98), (15, 25, 79), (24, 45, 71), (52, 87, 98), (20, 39, 82), (23, 33, 44), (43, 68, 88), (6, 8, 29), (36, 73, 95), (48, 78, 84), (22, 38, 84), (21, 65, 97), (30, 31, 57), (27, 28, 38), (2, 33, 46), (24, 29, 51), (4, 6, 45), (64, 71, 93), (14, 36, 68), (36, 51, 62), (20, 40, 68), (19, 71, 81), (33, 60, 81), (13, 25, 60), (17, 39, 68), (68, 69, 81), (18, 19, 89), (2, 28, 61), (4, 67, 71), (12, 26, 52), (34, 41, 46), (22, 27, 59), (28, 56, 96), (1, 25, 53), (39, 61, 90), (11, 31, 44), (17, 40, 82), (16, 21, 73), (19, 78, 93), (10, 16, 36), (21, 30, 32), (15, 23, 69), (9, 21, 28), (20, 29, 40), (11, 48, 61), (36, 71, 81), (19, 24, 48), (7, 49, 61), (15, 74, 99), (13, 45, 85)])
```

Comment: how did you get it to actually output that? I put set(list(itertools.combinations(numbers,3))) into a variable then tried to print that variable and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Actually, I did a print before the set(...)

Comment: print set(list(itertools.combinations(numbers,3)))

Comment: Alright sweet, thanks! I just did print(len(items)) since all i want is the # of combinations.